# Bullet-proof responsive HTML email

Tags: html, email, layout, responsive-design

I am testing a simple responsive HTML email which should be sent from a Qlikview server through the NPrinting extension. I am testing currently the HTML mockup with Putsmail and have successfully tested it on my own phone (Sony Xperia Z3 Compact) with exactly the code below.

But on my colleague's phone (some Samsung running Android 2.3.6) the responsiveness doesn't work anymore - it just ignores the media query and shows the two tables next to each other (instead of showing them below each other as expected on screens smaller than 600px).

Note that the other table border color CSS from the  section still works on my colleague's phone.

Any advice?

Note: If I change

```html
max-width: 599px
```

to

```html
max-device-width: 599px
```

the media query doesn't work on my phone either anymore.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <style type="text/css">
  @media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
   .responsive_table {
    display:block;
    width:300px;
   }
  }
  td {border: 1px solid #00f;}
  .responsive_table td {border: 1px solid #f00;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
This table should have 1 row and 2 columns on big screens.<br>
It should have 2 rows with 1 column each on mobile devices.

<table width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <table align="left" class="responsive_table">
    <tr>
     <td>Left</td>
    </tr>
   </table>

   <table align="right" class="responsive_table">
    <tr>
     <td>Right</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which client is your colleague using? The Android Gmail client doesn't support responsive mails, for example. When developing responsive mails, you really want to use a service like Litmus.com or Email On Acid for testing.

Comment: Developing responsive e-mails is not a fun activity, BTW. Apart from very simple layouts, there's no such thing as "bullet proof"; the supported features and amount of bugs vary widely between e-mail clients. You will spend a _lot_ of time trying to figure out why things don't work on some clients and how to work around it. You will learn to hate Gmail and Outlook 2007/2010/2013. I guarantee it :-)

Comment: My colleague's email client is MS Exchange (preinstalled Android email client).It's the same I am using.

For Desktop, I am testing with Outlook 2010, 2013, and Office 365 which should cover 95% of all our users.

Luckily, we don't use Gmail at all.

Comment: anybody have a suggestion?